# Clear input button renders differently when using component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have following material form:

```
       <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Email alebo ID používateľa</mat-label>
        <input
          #input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="123 | mail@mail.com"
          formControlName="inputValue"
        />

        <button
          matSuffix
          type="button"
          *ngIf="this.userForm.get('inputValue')!.value"
          mat-icon-button
          (click)="this.userForm.get('inputValue')?.setValue('')"
        >
          <mat-icon inline="true">close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Which displays the following result, where the 'x' clear button is on the same line as the input:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlpdX.png)

However, when I turn this button into a `clear-input-button.component.html` like this:

```
<button
  matSuffix
  type="button"
  *ngIf="control.value"
  mat-icon-button
  (click)="control?.setValue('')"
>
  <mat-icon inline="true">close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

and `.ts` file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clear-input-button',
  templateUrl: './clear-input-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clear-input-button.component.scss'],
})
export class ClearInputButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public control: any;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And finally use the same code but in component form:

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Email alebo ID používateľa</mat-label>
    <input
      #input
      matInput
      type="text"
      placeholder="123 | mail@mail.com"
      formControlName="inputValue"
    />
    <app-clear-input-button
      [control]="$any(this.userForm).get('inputValue')"
    >
    </app-clear-input-button>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The 'x' cancel button gets placed on another line and I don't know why it behaves like that, I expected component to behave the same way as the code but it seems to add some kind of wrapping to it.

[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPf1w.png)

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in hurry, but the problem in sthat, when Angular create the differents "divs", it's makes in a different way in one way or in another.

We can have a button-clear-component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-clear-component',
  template:`
  <button matSuffix type="button" mat-icon-button
     (click)="control?.setValue('')"
  >
      <mat-icon inline="true">close</mat-icon>
  </button>
  `,
  host:{
    'class':'mat-form-field-suffix',
    
  }
})
export class ButtonClearComponent {
  @Input() control:any;

  constructor(public el:ElementRef){}
}
```

And a directive form-field-clear.directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[add-clear-button]',
 
})
export class FormClearDirective implements OnInit {
  obs: any;
  ref:ComponentRef<ButtonClearComponent>
  control:any
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private vcr:ViewContainerRef,
    private ngControl:NgControl
  ) {
    this.control=ngControl.control
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ref=this.vcr.createComponent(ButtonClearComponent);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.control = this.ngControl.control
      this.ref.instance.control=this.control;
      
      this.obs = this.control.valueChanges
        .pipe(startWith(this.control.value))
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.ref.instance.el.nativeElement.style.visibility=res?null:'hidden'
        });
        this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(this.ref.instance.el.nativeElement);
        
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.obs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You use like

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Email alebo ID používateľa</mat-label>
    <input
      add-clear-button
      matInput
      type="text"
      placeholder="123 | mail@mail.com"
      formControlName="inputValue"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrda3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-clear.directive.ts)

NOTE: in the stackblitz there're another directive button-clear.directive that it's applied to a mat-button mat-icon

**NOTE2**: perhafs all the before is too complex and it's only inject the ElementRef in our custom button and change this parent in ngAfterViewInit (or enclosed by a setTimeout())

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
ngOnInit()
{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(
         this.el.nativeElement);
  })
}
```

but I'm not pretty sure that work

Comment: Thank you, injecting the ElementRef and changing it's parent (NOTE2) was enough to solve my problem.